# How to send additional variable with rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am working with a rails form which takes users text input and sends it to the controller.
It sends two infos, the text and the language of the text (I18n.locale variable). My form looks something like that:

```
    <%= form_for(:text, :url => {:action => 'create'} ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :content, "#{t :"Write whatever you want"}" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content, :cols => 80, :rows => 3 %> <br />
    <%=  f.hidden_field :locale, :value => I18n.locale %>
    <%= f.submit "#{t :Post}"%>
<% end %>
```

I am sending that locale value using a hidden field. But I think this is a bad practice. User can easily modify this form. So is there any way to send that locale value among other form data automatically without any visible/hidden field?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid modifing data by user maybe you can use session like locale_session = "en", and use that session when you are dealing with data in controller

Comment: Temporary solved this adding another line on controller  `def create
 @text = Microblog.new(params[:text])
 @text.update_attributes(params[@text.locale = "#{I18n.locale}" ])`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of adding variable with rails form

```
<%=  f.hidden_field :locale, :value => I18n.locale %>
```

AND

```
<%= form_for(:text, :url => {:action => 'create', :locale => I18n.locale} ) do |f| %>
```

But both of the above can easily modified by the user.

To avoid this either you have to use [`sessions`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions) or [`ssl`](http://www.sslshopper.com/why-ssl-the-purpose-of-using-ssl-certificates.html) page

Comment: `<%= form_for(:text, :url => {:action => 'create', :locale => I18n.locale} ) do |f| %>` didn't work. I got nil for locale value.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solved this adding another line into controller. Not sure it it safe or not

```
def create
@text = Microblog.new(params[:text])
@text.update_attributes(params[@text.locale = "#{I18n.locale}" ])
```